# How to parse output from a kubectl command into an array for a bash script

Tags: bash, kubectl

I have this kubectl command which gives me the following output. I need to know how to store the output in an array, so I can loop through each of those and further issue gcloud commands on the resources.

```
kubectl get ingress test-load-balancer -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/backends}'| jq  -r 'keys'

[
  "k8s-be-30423--12305b0f030d5a48",
  "k8s-be-31245--10023b0f030d5a48"
]
```

However, now I need to run individual commands for these k8s-xx resources inside a bash script. I tried the following but it doesn't save the output in an array

```
read BACKEND_SERVICES<<<$(kubectl get ingress cysiv-load-balancer -o \

jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/backends}'| jq -r 'keys')
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I meant to say, I tried the following but it did not work.  
read -t  BACKEND_SERVICES<<<$(kubectl get ingress cysiv-load-balancer -o \
  jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/backends}'| jq -r 'keys')

Comment: Looks like you should split the command in two parts. First get *jsonpath*, then: *read -t BACKEND_SERVICES<<<$(kubectl get ingress cysiv-load-balancer -o $jsonpath)*

Comment: Add kubectl's output to your question.

Comment: This is the kubectl output. If you have a way to directly get the 'keys' from kubectl, that would be great as well

kubectl get ingress cysiv-load-balancer -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/backends}'

{"k8s-be-30423--74546b0f030d5a48":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31245--74546b0f030d5a48":"HEALTHY"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your keys does not contain spaces.

```
array=($(kubectl ... | jq -r 'keys[]'))
declare -p array
```