# Output from kubectl images into an array (bash script)

Tags: arrays, bash, kubectl

I'm following the format of [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841587/how-to-parse-output-from-a-kubectl-command-into-an-array-for-a-bash-script) to try and get the jsonpath for images (for all pods) into an array, which I can then loop through and run a gcloud command on each item from the array.

The command I'm trying is:

```
array=( $(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" | jq -r 'keys[]') )
declare -p array
```

However I receive the error: `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 41`

When i run the command without the `jq` the command it's putting everything into the first index item, so a big long string, with spaces e.g.

```
typeset -a array=( 'eu.gcr.io/repo/imagename1 eu.gcr.io/repo/imagename2 eu.gcr.io/repo/imagename3 eu.gcr.io/repo/imagename4' )
```

Any ideas how I can get this output into separate array items and something I can use to iterate through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `-o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}"` outputs all of the image names on one line (here's mine):

```
nginx docker.local/node-server:1640867594 docker.local/node-server:1640867594 docker.local/node-server:1640867594 nginx nginx nginx nginx nginx
```

It's no longer JSON, so piping it into `jq` is going to do weird things. In your case, jq is (probably) complaining about one of the `:` items. In my case, I get a slightly different parse error.

Either drop the use of `jq`, or lean into it fully:

```
kubectl get pods -o json | jq -r '.items[].spec.containers[].image' | sort | uniq | ...
```